# deploy rails app to two domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I want to deploy my rails app to two domains

```
lab.mysitename.com
mysitename.com
```

the lab site should have different database than the main site. basically I want to do some experiments on the lab site and I want to give access to specific users.

I am using cap deploy:cold to deploy to the main app (mysitename.com).

I want something following this scenario

```
-- do something risky or fun to have 
--> deploy to lab.mysitename.com
-- users play with the site and modify a sandboxed database (not the main database). everything looks great and the team loved it 
--> deploy to the main site (mysitename.com)
```

Comment: You forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.kwatee.net

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is via capistrano's [multistage](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) extension.

This allows you to isolate some of your capistrano settings (such as which hosts to deploy to, or where on disk to deploy to if you want everything in the same server) into separate files.

You then do

```
cap production deploy
```

For it to deploy using the settings for your production stage and

```
cap labs deploy
```

For it to deploy to your labs stage.

What exactly a stage is sort of up to you. You could have it use a different database.yml or deploy a specific branch of your repository for example.